# How to run two asynchronous tasks one after another ?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have tow asynctasks that I want that they run separately when I click on a button. I mean when the button is clicked the second one wont start until the first is already finished.
By the way, i've tried to use :

```
if(task1.getStatus()==AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){
task2.excecute();
}
```

But it doesn't work ...

Any help please?

Comment: you can put `task2.execute();` in `onPostExecute` of `task1`

Comment: If you want two things (A and B) done asynchronously, such that B runs after A, why not just create a *single* task that does A then B?

Comment: @hamzaoui you need to call first task then make onPostExecute method then call second Asyntask in that on PostExecute method . that solve

Comment: @shayanpourvatan it doesn't solve the problem , it still run in parallel

Comment: @hamzaouiaymen it's not possible, because `onPostExecute` run after task has been completed, i think your problem is some where else.

Answer (score 1):

Since HONEYCOMB, when using `execute()`, "tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution." So your AsyncTasks should run one after the other by default.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

How are you verifying that this isn't the case?

Comment: But when i make : task1.execute(); task2.execute(); they run at the same time , that's the problem !

Comment: May I ask how you've tested that they run at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

The if-statement does not wait until the condition is fullfilled. It just evaluates the condition, and if it's true, it executes the statement in the if block, otherwise the thread continues with the statement after the if block. Actually you have to wait for the condition.

The simplest method would be to just implement a wait loop:

```
while ( task1.getStatus()!=AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED )
{
    Thread.sleep( 10 );
}
task2.execute();
```

But this approach has the main drawback that the actual thread is blocking. Consider to use the Future framework introduced with java 6 to solve your problem